# Splitting string by regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following code snippet:

```
var colorText = "red,blue,green,yellow";
var colors3 = colorText.split(/[^\,]+/);
alert(colors3); // ["", ",", ",", ",", ""]
```

I don't understand what's going on here. As far as I understand, the regular expression will match any commas at the beginning of a string, and it matches 1 or more of these strings. What happens when we provide this regular expression as the argument to `split`? Surely, if we just tried to match the regex against `colorText`, we'd be getting no match, because the starting character is not a comma. But how does the regex provided to `split` lead to an array of commas and two empty string on each side?

Comment: What is it you're trying to split on? Also, that's a character group, and it's not "start of string", it's "everything but not commas", you'd have to move `^` out of the character group to match start of string.

Comment: First of all your regex is off. The ^ operator is going to match everything BUT a comma. You also need to add the flag g so your regex should look like this /[\,]+/g. That will match all commas in a string

Comment: Caret must be at the start of the regex, what you did is to exclude multiple commas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained in [MDN web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-negated-character-set) `[^xyz]`

> A negated or complemented character set. That is, it matches anything that is not enclosed in the brackets.

Your regex `/[^\,]+/` will match any sequence of characters that doesn't include any comma.

So your regex will match these sequences in `colorText`:

- `red`
- `blue`
- `green`
- `yellow`

and the `split` function will split `colorText` at those sequences.

However, if you want to split your string at each comma, use this:

```
colors = colorText.split(',');
```

Answer (score 3):

Why do you need a regex when you can simply do `split(',')` ?

```js
var colorText = "red,blue,green,yellow";
var colors3 = colorText.split(',');
console.log(colors3);
```

If you want to select everything but the comma then maybe using `match` is a better idea.

```js
var colorText = ",red,blue,green,yellow";
var colors3 = colorText.match(/[^\,]+/g);
console.log(colors3);
```

Comment: it looks like, that the op want to prevent splitting with a starting comma and get an empty item in the array.

Comment: @NinaScholz I updated the answer with your suggestion, but I saw you answered too.

Answer (score 1):

If you like to prevent empty items on splitting, you could use [`String#match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScrdipt/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) instead of [`String#split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) and a regular expression which matches all characters except commas.

```js
var regex = /[^,]+/g;

console.log(",red,blue,green,yellow,".match(regex));
console.log("red,blue,green,yellow".match(regex));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

So, my goal was not to separate the words in the string by comma. I found this code in a book and wanted to understand it. The mistake I made was that I thought that the `^` matched the beginning of a string, while in fact it means "anything but" inside of square brackets. Now I understand that the regular expression matches any number of character that is not a comma, and that's what tells `split()` what to put in each list element. The first and last elements are empty strings because that's what at the left and right side of the first and last words, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove that caret `^` from `var colors3 = colorText.split(/[^\,]+/);` so that it works well:

```js
var colorText = "red,blue,green,yellow";
var colors3 = colorText.split(/[\,]+/);
console.log(colors3);
```